# how to render html page in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

hello guys i m new to loopback, can anyone help me with this following things
when we install loopback by default we have client folder when we can place all our front end file now place all html file there  and render these html file from router for eg ;-

```
var router = server.loopback.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index');
});
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
res.render('login');
});
```

i want something like this i have index,login html file in client folder so how i can do that i does lots of google but haven't find any soultion like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Assuming you created your project via loopback's CLI, you should have a `server/boot/root.js` file.

   ```
   'use strict';

   module.exports = function(server) {
     // Install a `/` route that returns server status
     var router = server.loopback.Router();
     router.get('/', server.loopback.status());
     server.use(router);
   };
   ```

   Either remove or change the route to `server.loopback.status()` (e.g. `router.get('/status', server.loopback.status())`.
2. In `server/middleware.json`, you should see a line near the bottom with `"files": {},`.

   Modify it to the following:

   ```
   "files": {
     "loopback#static": {
       "params": "$!../client"
     }
   },
   ```
3. Place all your static files into the `client` directory.

This is from loopback's documentation: [Add a static web page](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Add-a-static-web-page.html). I'd recommend going through all the [Getting started with LoopBack](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Getting-started-with-LoopBack.html) documentation if you are new.

Comment: this  "params": "$!../client" will set just one file for eg:- index.html/ejs if i place all html file like login / home.html etc then how i will render these file for router

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the answer so that it may work for the people for whom the Previous answer din work, I would like to suggest some other approach that worked for me.

inside server/boot/root.js file add the below code:

```
'use strict';
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function(server) {
  // Install a `/` route that returns server status
  const router = server.loopback.Router();
  router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./../../client','index.html'));
  });
  server.use(router);
};
```